# word document to highlight word 'just like spellcheck' which should not be used in the document

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I work on word document which need to comply with the 'Simplified Technical English' (STE) standard. STE is a is a controlled language for the preparation of technical documentation used in the aerospace industry. It is dictionary of sort, which will tell the words to be used and not to be used. Check out Page 104 of this link to understand the usage and scenario. [STE100](https://robertobertuol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ASD-STE100-ISSUE-7.pdf)

I want to understand the possibility of MS Word document to highlight (just like incorrect spelling) the words which are not meant to be used in a document.

I tried to google for solution, I could find solution on VBA. I am looking for direction, if it is possible to do it just like spell check in realtime rather than running a VBA code.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Answer (score 0):

You change the Spell Check by changing the spelling dictionary. Since you don't know how to do that, you should ask in SuperUser.

Since STE is a standard, it is certain that someone has already created a custom STE dictionary. Is there an online community for STE? If so, you should ask them where you can get an STE dictionary for MS Word.